# Maximum area of a triangles intersection in trapezium.

Tags: geometry, optimization

I have a trapezium $ABCD$. On $AB$ I choose point $K$ and on $CD$ I choose point $L$. Let $C$ denote area of intersection of triangles $ALB$ and $CKD$. How to choose $K$ and $L$ so the area $C$ is maximized (and how to prove correctnes of this choice)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We may notice for first that $[LNK]=[DNA]$ and $[LMK]=[CMB]$.
$[DNA]$ only depends on the harmonic mean between $DL$ and $AK$,
$[CMB]$ only depends on the harmonic mean between $CL$ and $BK$.

It follows that our problem is equivalent to maximizing 
$$ \frac{xy}{x+y}+\frac{XY}{X+Y} $$

under the constraints $x+X=CD$ and $y+Y=AB$. With a bit of calculus, it is straightforward to deduce that the maximum is achieved at $\frac{x}{X}=\frac{y}{Y}$, i.e. when the $KL$ line goes through $BC\cap AD$.